# Calculated properties in OOP

Tags: java, object-oriented

Is there any convention on how to declare, name, use or access object properties that themselves **do not add new information and could be re-calculated** at any point in time? Basic example (made this one up, just for clarification):

```
class User {
    // provided by DB
    int ID;
    // calculated
    boolean id_is_odd;

    // provided by DB
    Timestamp[] visits;
    // calculated
    long shortest_time_between_visits;
}
```

Since checking an Integer for whether it's even or odd, I would implement `id_is_odd()` as a member function.

But maybe `visits` is very big and one should avoid calculating `shortest_time_between_visits` multiple times. So what to do with it? Should I make a getter which checks if `private shortest_time_between_visits` is null and if so, calculates it first? Would that even be called a "getter" when we are retrieving only a calculated value? Or defining in constructor? Are there even any standards defining a difference between native and calculated properties? I could not find any information on that.

I tagged java, but this problem can be applied to more languages with object support like Javascript.

Comment: I sometimes use `calcFoo()`, but, as the other answers state, `getFoo()` is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several concerns on your question, I'll try to address some of them.

> Is there any convention on how to declare, name, use or access object properties that themselves do not add new information and could be re-calculated at any point in time?

Any object has identity, state and behavior. Identity is what makes an object different from other objects, state is what an object knows about itself, its self-encapsulated knowledge, and behavior is what services it can provide for others. So in your first example, as you said, id oddness knowledge doesn't add up to object's state, so it definitely should be its behavior. But in order to keep `User` class clean and following the policy that data and behavior should reside together, I would create a `UserId` class and put method `isOdd` there. If you're into [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), it's widely spread practice to create its own classes for entity's IDs.

> But maybe visits is very big and one should avoid calculating shortest_time_between_visits multiple times. So what to do with it?

There are several options here. First, nothing prevents you from doing it in a database. So as a result you get a `Visits` object with all required data already calculated. It makes sense if it is really very big, as you say. Databases are good at it.

If you're ready to calculate it in application itself, there is a technique called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Basically, it's a simple cache. Each time your functions is called, it checks if the result for given arguments was already calculated. If it was, the result is returned. If not -- it's calculated and put in cache. But again, I would definitely make a separate class for that. And [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization) is a generic solution for java 8.

There are also languages with native support for this kind of problems. The technique they use is called [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Besides the expressions are evaluated only at the point when they are actually used, they are evaluated only once.

> Would that even be called a "getter" when we are retrieving only a
>   calculated value?

In order to keep your objects encapsulated, nobody should know if you retrieve a property or calculated value. So your methods should look the same and follow the same naming policy. It's called the [Uniform Access Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle).

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you are approaching the question wrong. Getters are just a kind of member function (as I read it,you think about these as special functions that maps fairly directly to backing storage). But this is precisely the kind of internal knowledge that OOP should hide from the user of your object and from outside all “access points” should look alike.

The important thing is to ensure you maintain consistent state in the object, usually easiest achieved by not storing more data than needed and calculate as many results as you can. (Strictly speaking a simple getter is also a calculated value, the simplest one, conceptually 1 * backing store).

Also consider that in most languages there are syntactic sugar to easily generate basic setter/getter pairs but you could just as well write them out fully and then you can easier see there is really no conceptual difference between these and other member function. (In fact I tend to do just that as I have found it is very rarely I need only the simplest getter and eventually I will have to flesh it out to add more features to it)

Further the idea is that you should be able to change the internals without anyone outside noticing. So if you start with one stored data item and calculating the various representation from that as you suggest then you can test and see if there are performance issues. If it is then change it, maybe you need to have another internal representation and change the simpler getter of the original data to a more complex calculation or maybe as you say you find some issues with long calculation times, in which case you can improve that by an internal cache, but do not prematurely add complexity. If you do this you typically need an extra functionality in you setter to drop the cache when changing the backing data which brings me back to my previous point about needing more advanced setters/getters than the auto generated ones.

Answer (score 2):

The Uniform Access Principle tells us that:

> All services offered by a module should be available through a uniform
>   notation, which does not betray whether they are implemented through
>   storage or through computation.

This means that, from outside the class, it should be impossible to tell if the information returned by simply referencing a variable or doing a calculation.

That said, there can be value to the caller to know the *time* complexity of the service. Your `id_is_odd` getter has a time complexity of O(1) just like `ID` whereas `shortest_time_between_visits` has a complexity of O(n), also it could throw an exception or return a sentinel value. For these reasons, a good argument can be made to expose this service differently than the other two.

I would make `shortest_time_between_visits` a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [good blog post](https://lytk.in/posts/calculated-properties-three-strategies) describing different approaches to this topic and when to use each. You can choose best approach based on your needs.